# Kimball Modelling One Column Linking to Many Dimensions

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2016, data-warehouse

We are conducting Quality inspections, Appraisals, and Ratings on furniture. Many different types of furniture exist, chairs (1), shelves (2), couches (3), table (4). The respective DimProductType is 1,2,3,4. We actually have 100+ product types.

If measuring facts for brown tables, or chairs with 6 six legs, or Couches with  polyester fabric type, how would I model the Fact table ?

In FactInspection, there are two proposed methods.
What is best Kimball design for this?

DimProductTypeProductId linking to many dimension tables below in one column, Or have denormalized columns for each furniture with nulls (with 100+ product types)

What is the official Kimball way to model this?

**Method 1:**

```
(this will join, on DimProductTypeProductId Composite)

create table dbo.FactInspection
(
    FactInspectionId int primary key identity(1,1)
    DimInspectionDate int not null,
    ValueAmount numeric(10,2)not null,
    StarRatingOutof10 int not null,
    DimProductTypeProductId null
)
```

**Method 2:**

```
create table dbo.FactInspection
(
    FactInspectionId int primary key identity(1,1)
    DimInspectionDate int not null,
    ValueAmount numeric(10,2) not null,
    StarRatingOutof10 int not null,
    DimChairId int null,
    DimShelfId int null,
    DimCouchId int null,
    etc.. 
)
```

**Dimension Tables:**

```
create table dbo.DimChair
(
    DimChairId int primary key identity(1,1),
    ProductType int,
    ChairNaturalKey int,
    ProductTypeAndNaturalKey as (ProductType + '|' ChairNaturalKey) persisted
    Color varchar(55),
    LegNumber int
)

create table dbo.DimShelf
(
    DimShelfId int primary key identity(1,1),
    ProductType int,
    ShelfNaturalKey int,
    ProductTypeAndNaturalKey as (ProductType + '|' ShelfNaturalKey ) persisted
    Length float,
    Height float,
    NumberofShelves varchar(55)
)

create table dbo.DimCouch
(
    DimCouchId int primary key identity(1,1),
    ProductType int,
    CouchNaturalKey int,
    ProductTypeAndNaturalKey as (ProductType + '|' CouchNaturalKey) persisted
    FabricType varchar(255),
    NumberofSeats int
)
```

Comment: Why not use a durable key for performance reasons? Surely every category has its own sub-category. The point is more about how can it be leveraged to answer questions later (say comparing similar? I hope your always focusing on answering business questions (why don’t people buy 5-legged chairs but will purchase black 7-legged ones when they are on sale? Is it merely the price that dissuades? )

Comment: added natural durable key, we want to be able to analyze on different attributes, for sales and quality analytics department, etc

Comment: I could also use a Guid for all the dimension tables, may not be optimal performance, however could operate as supernatural durable key